# CSV to TableView skips header (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, tableview

I find TableView already confusing as it is, but the code I have now works okay except for the minor part: the Country, Capital, Population, Democracy aren't shown as the header, but rather show up in the first row of TableView because in the text file they're also in the first row. How can I fix this?

```
public class TabV extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch (args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Collection<CountryData> list = Files.readAllLines(new File("c:/tableviewinputs.txt").toPath())
            .stream()
            .map(line -> {
                String[] details = line.split(",");
                CountryData cd = new CountryData();
                cd.setCountry(details[0]);
                cd.setCapital(details[1]);
                cd.setPopulation(details[2]);
                cd.setDemocracy(details[3]);
                return cd;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    ObservableList<CountryData> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

    TableView<CountryData> tableView = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<CountryData, String> c1 = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<CountryData, String> c2 = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<CountryData, String> c3 = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<CountryData, String> c4 = new TableColumn<>();

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(c1, c2, c3, c4);

    c1.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().countryProperty());
    c2.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().capitalProperty());
    c3.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().populationProperty());
    c4.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().democracyProperty());

    tableView.setItems(details);

    StackPane stack = new StackPane(tableView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 365, 220);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


private class CountryData {
    StringProperty country = new SimpleStringProperty();
    StringProperty capital = new SimpleStringProperty();
    StringProperty population = new SimpleStringProperty();
    StringProperty democracy = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final StringProperty countryProperty() {
        return this.country;
    }


    public final void setCountry(final java.lang.String country) {
        this.countryProperty().set(country);
    }

    public final StringProperty capitalProperty() {
        return this.capital;
    }


    public final void setCapital(final java.lang.String capital) {
        this.capitalProperty().set(capital);
    }

    public final StringProperty populationProperty() {
        return this.population;
    }

    public final void setPopulation(final java.lang.String population) {
        this.populationProperty().set(population);
    }

    public final StringProperty democracyProperty() {
        return this.democracy;
    }

    public final void setDemocracy(final java.lang.String democracy) {
        this.democracyProperty().set(democracy);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(new File("c:/tableviewinputs.txt").toPath());

String[] headers = allLines.get(0).split(",");

Collection<CountryData> list = allLines.stream()
        .skip(1)
        .map(line -> {
            String[] details = line.split(",");
            CountryData cd = new CountryData();
            cd.setCountry(details[0]);
            cd.setCapital(details[1]);
            cd.setPopulation(details[2]);
            cd.setDemocracy(details[3]);
            return cd;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

ObservableList<CountryData> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

TableView<CountryData> tableView = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<CountryData, String> c1 = new TableColumn<>(headers[0]);
TableColumn<CountryData, String> c2 = new TableColumn<>(headers[1]);
TableColumn<CountryData, String> c3 = new TableColumn<>(headers[2]);
TableColumn<CountryData, String> c4 = new TableColumn<>(headers[3]);
```